# How to animate sublayer contents?

Tags: swift, core-animation, caanimation

I have a layer and want to create an animation for this layer which will update contents of one of sublayers. CAAnimation `keyPath` has a notation, like `sublayers.layerName.propertyName` to update some values of a sublayer but seems like it doesn't work with `.contents` property.

```
    func rightStepAfter(_ t: Double) -> CAAnimation {
        let rightStep = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "sublayers.right.contents")
        rightStep.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        rightStep.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        rightStep.values = [UIImage(named:"leftfoot")!.cgImage!, UIImage(named:"rightfoot")!.cgImage!]
        rightStep.beginTime = t
        rightStep.duration = stepDuration
        rightStep.fillMode = .forwards
        return rightStep
    }
    func leftStepAfter(_ t: Double) -> CAAnimation {
        let leftStep = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "sublayers.left.opacity")
        leftStep.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        leftStep.keyTimes = [0, 1]
        leftStep.values = [0, 1]
        leftStep.beginTime = t
        leftStep.duration = stepDuration
        leftStep.fillMode = .forwards
        return leftStep
    }
```

Here `leftStepAfter` creates correct animation which updates opacity of a sublayer and `rightStepAfter` doesn't update `contents` of a sublayer. If you remove `sublayers.right.` from the keyPath - animation will correctly change contents of a CURRENT layer. [Project to check it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aUr04QP6xcN46E1Cvvhw8pRtGa4XLfUl/view?usp=sharing) and [the original project](https://github.com/DuncanMC/AnimationGroups).

Why my animation doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: I've only had limited success animating sublayers. I generally have to create and submit separate animations targeted directly to each layer that I want to animate.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option, because I want to add that layer to video via mainCompositionInst.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer) where all layers added on parentLayer and seems like animation will play only if attached to topmost layers on the parentLayer.

Comment: So why does that preclude adding animations to each layer separately? Create the layers, add the sublayers, add them to the parent layer, and then add animations to each layer as needed. That should work just fine. It's a pain, but it works.

Comment: Hmmmm.... somehow it just works now (on the latest iOS) but I thought I already tried (actually it was my first approach) to just create separate animations for layer and for it's sublayer and saw some issues with timeOffset and synchronisations of this animations, but it seems it works as expected.

Comment: Could you add an answer to your question and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find an answer to my original question (via keypath), but solved my problem by creating several animations for each sublayer.